# Can someone give me a script to great shaded error plots instead of error bars with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following script for plotting how increasing epochlength effects the AEC, PLI and PLT (measures of functional connectivity in the brain). Instead of error bars I want shaded areas around the lines, but I cannot work out how to do that!

```
ggplot(data=epochlength, aes(x=el, y=Mean, group=measure, colour=measure)) +
  ggtitle("Effect of Epoch Length on PLI, AEC and PLT") +
  geom_line(data=PLIdata, aes(x=el, y=upperboundPLI)) +
  geom_line(data=PLIdata, aes(x=el, y=lowerboundPLI)) +
  geom_line(data=PLTdata, aes(x=el, y=upperboundPLT)) +
  geom_line(data=PLTdata, aes(x=el, y=lowerboundPLT)) +
  geom_line(data=AECdata, aes(x=el, y=upperboundAEC)) +
  geom_line(data=AECdata, aes(x=el, y=lowerboundAEC)) +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), limits=c(0,1)) +
  geom_line(linetype="solid", size=1.2) +
  xlab("Epochlength (seconds)") + 
  ylab("PLI / AEC / PLT Score") +
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("1/8", "1/4", "1/2", "1", "2", "4", "8", "16"))
```

I plotted the errors as lines but cannot work out how to shade between them (or if there is another better way to do this).

[image]

Comment: The simplest way would be to reshape your data - if you posted a data sample using `dput(epochlength)` we could experiment and show you what this means.

Comment: `geom_ribbon(aes(x=el, ymin=lowerboundPLI, ymax=upperboundPLI))` etc would most likely be helpful.  Also, `limits=c(0,1)` is a dangerous habit to get into because it filters the input before plotting.  `coord_cartesian` is safer, because it uses all the input and then "zooms" to the requested area.

Answer (score 0):

1. Combine the data, it reduces the number of `geom_*` calls you need (and therefore improves readability/maintainability).
2. We can use `geom_ribbon` for that.

Try this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

bind_rows(
  rename(PLIdata, upperbound = upperboundPLI, lowerbound = lowerboundPLI),
  rename(PLTdata, upperbound = upperboundPLT, lowerbound = lowerboundPLT),
  rename(AECdata, upperbound = upperboundAEC, lowerbound = lowerboundAEC)
) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = el, y = Mean, color = measure, fill = measure, group = measure)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = lowerbound, ymax = upperbound), alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

Notes:

1. We don't need `dplyr` for this, but its `bind_rows` is convenient for things like this.
2. If there are other columns in frames that are not shared among all of them, this should still work (since we're using only the names we know we have in common), but you'll find that a column in one and not another will have `NA` values in the other. Again, not a problem here but good to know. You may benefit from a more robust `rename`ing step if you have other needs, too.

---

Data

```r
set.seed(42)
PLIdata <- data.frame(measure = "PLI", el = 1:4, Mean = sample(10, size = 4)) |>
  transform(lowerboundPLI = Mean - runif(4), upperboundPLI = Mean + runif(4))
PLTdata <- data.frame(measure = "PLT", el = 1:4, Mean = sample(10, size = 4)) |>
  transform(lowerboundPLT = Mean - runif(4), upperboundPLT = Mean + runif(4))
AECdata <- data.frame(measure = "AEC", el = 1:4, Mean = sample(10, size = 4)) |>
  transform(lowerboundAEC = Mean - runif(4), upperboundAEC = Mean + runif(4))
PLIdata
```